# How can I retrieve ko.computed running sum of foreach when iterating through observablearray in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, foreach, knockout.js

I have a list of ProjectPeriod items as an observableArray in a knockout viewModel which includes the number of months in each period. I want to display the end date for each row in the foreach. Currently I am using a ko.computed value in the viewModel, but I'm not able to loop over each item up to the item being displayed. How can I loop over and sum the values being displayed only up to the current item in the foreach?

Currently I have the following HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr class="tableHeader">
        <th>Period</th>
        <th>Number of Months</th>
        <th>End of Period</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: ProjectPeriod">
        <tr>
            <td><input data-bind="value: ProjectYearText" /></td>
            <td><input data-bind="value: PeriodMonths" /></td>
            <td data-bind="text: endDate"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the following viewModel:

```
function ProjectPeriod(projectYearId, projectYearText, periodMonths, viewModel) {
    var self = this;
        self.ProjectYearId = projectYearId;
        self.ProjectYearText = ko.observable(projectYearText);
        self.PeriodMonths = ko.observable(periodMonths);
        self.viewModel = viewModel;

        self.endDate = ko.computed(function () {
            var startDate = hfProjectDates.Get("ProjectStartDate");

            // Calculate the number of months from the beginning to the current period.
            var monthCount = 0;
            ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.viewModel.ProjectPeriods(), function (projectPeriod) {
                if (projectPeriod.ProjectYearId < self.ProjectYearId)
                    monthCount += projectPeriod.PeriodMonths;
                });

            var endDate = moment(startDate).add('M', monthCount);
            return endDate ? endDate.format("M/DD/YYYY") : "None";
        });
    }

    function ProjectPeriodViewModel() {
        // Data
        var self = this;

        self.ProjectPeriods = ko.observableArray([
            new ProjectPeriod(1, "1st Year", 12, ProjectPeriodViewModel),
            new ProjectPeriod(2, "2nd Year", 12, ProjectPeriodViewModel),
            new ProjectPeriod(3, "3rd Year", 12, ProjectPeriodViewModel)
        ]);

    }
```

I am really just getting started with Knockout, so I expect there are more than a few issues with the way I'm approaching this. But specifically I need to get the running end date to display.

**Update:** based on Matt;s feedback I've updated to include the observable in ProjectPeriod, but I'm running into issues getting the reference from the viewModel and iterating over the array.

Comment: Not sure what you want. Do you want a cumulative number of months at the end of each row? So 12 months for the first row, 24 for the second and so on?

Comment: Yes, essentially that's what I need. the period of months is entered in the input boxes. I need each row to show the end date. So, row 1 may have 5 months and periodEndDate will be startdate + 5 months, row 2 has 12 months entered and periodEndDate will be startdate + 17 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this, what I would probably do is move the computed property to the `ProjectPeriod` object itself and also give the `ProjectPeriod` a reference to the parent `ProjectPeriodViewModel`, that way, the `ProjectPeriod` will be able to access the `ProjectPeriods` and count backwards adding up all the periods that came before it (it might be an idea to give each period an index property to make this simpler).

Comment: I'm beginning to go down this path as well. I already have an Id which I can enumerate over, but have been stuck in how to add a reference to the ProjectPeriodViewModel. do you have an example of how this might look?

Comment: @tlbignerd: I think you have it based on your last edit. I'd just pass the `ProjectPeriodViewModel` as an argument to the constructor. Your problem might be here `ko.utils.arrayForEach(viewModel.ProjectPeriods()...` Shouldn't that be `self.viewModel.ProjectPeriods()`?

Comment: I thought I was close as well. I put in the self.viewModel, and passed the ProjectPeriodVewModel in the constructor (originally I was using self as a parameter). When I run this I receive the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ProjectPeriods'